# Laravel Storaget get file contents

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to know if you do the following in my code below how do you check if the file exists e.g

```
{
    $file = Storage::disks('local')->get($file);
    // then test if $file exists
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a clear example in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#retrieving-files), if you take a look.

```
$exists = Storage::disk('s3')->exists('file.jpg');
```

Comment: What about if it's stored in public folder is it just exisits('public/ . $file);

Comment: If you look at the [filesystem](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/filesystems.php#L51) config file, you'll see there's a `public` disk defined. `$exists = Storage::disk('public')->exists('file.jpg');`

Answer (score 5):

You can check the existence of the file with the code below for your local storage,

```
$file_exists = Storage::disk('local')->exists($file);
```

You can read more about storage on Laravel Document at [Laravel Filesystem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#retrieving-files).
**Note:** in the document you will check `disk('s3')`. It depends on what connection we are using defined in `config/filesystem.php`(the configuration file for the filesystem in laravel).

OR simply you can use check the condition by

```
if(Storage::disk('local')->exists($file)) { 

}
```

It will also work for you.